# ECDSA_do_verify is throwing error

Tags: openssl, ecdsa

ECDSA verify signature failed

```
 if (ECDSA_do_verify(digest.data, digest.len, sig, ec_key)) {
      printf("successful");
    } else {
         printf("Error in signing");
        while ((l=ERR_get_error_line_data(&file,&line,&data,&flags)) != 0) { 
            syslog(LOG_ERR, "ECDSA_do_verify Error %x : %s : %s : %d",
                    l, ERR_error_string(l,buf), file,line);
        }
}
```

Error:-

> ECDSA_do_verify Error 3208408d :
>   error:3208408D:lib(50):func(132):reason(141) : fec_crypto_api.c : 249
>
> ECDSA_do_verify Error 320c308d :
>   error:320C308D:lib(50):func(195):reason(141) : fec_key.c : 111
>
> ECDSA_do_verify Error 320af066 :
>   error:320AF066:lib(50):func(175):reason(102) : fec_crypto.c : 2090
>
> ECDSA_do_verify Error 3206807b :
>   error:3206807B:lib(50):func(104):reason(123) : fec_crypto_api.c : 587

How to fix this?

Comment: I have the private key of ecdsa in BER format, input which needs to be signed and wants to generate a signature using both of them. What sequence of steps to be used

Comment: You should probably use the EVP interfaces. For an example of using them, see [EVP Signing and Verifying](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: How to convert ecdsa key ber/der format to openssl object?